# Problem with cython compiled objects and multiprocessing on Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, cython

I have an objects library compiled using cython. When I try to use these objects on a simple script using python 3 with multiproccessing (Pool) python throws a pickling error. The weird thing is that if I use python 2, everithing works as expected (compiling the code with cython in python 2 an running it with python 2). Moreover, when I try a simple script to actually pickle the cython objects on python 3 (without multiprocessing) no problem is found.

Here is a small example of what I have:

**example_lib.pyx:**

```
'''
example_lib.pyx
'''

#import numpy as np

include "cython_object.pyx"
```

**cython_object.pyx:**

```
cdef class CythonObject:
    def __init__(self, str name, int a, int b):

        self._name = name
        self._a = a
        self._b = b

    property Name:
        '''
        Returns the name of the object.
        '''   
        def __get__(self):
            return self._name

    property A:
        '''
        Returns a.
        '''   
        def __get__(self):
            return self._a

    property B:
        '''
        Returns b.
        '''   
        def __get__(self):
            return self._b

    cpdef getSum(self):
        return self._a + self._b

    cpdef dict pack(self):
        cdef dict pack = { 'name': self._name
                         , 'a'   : self._a
                         , 'b'   : self._b
                         }
        return pack

    cpdef unPack(self, dict pack):
        self._name = str(pack['name'])
        self._a = int(pack['a'])
        self._b = int(pack['b'])
```

**example_lib_setup:**

```
try:
    from setuptools import setup
    from setuptools import Extension
except ImportError:
    from distutils.core import setup
    from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import numpy

setup(
    name = 'cythonobjects'
   ,ext_modules = cythonize("example_lib.pyx")
   ,include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()]
)
```

test.py:

```
import multiprocessing
from example_lib import *

def runReplica(inputs):
    (i, objs) = inputs
    for obj,pack in objs:
        obj.unPack(pack)
        print('Rep:{}. Name: {}. {} + {} = {}'.format(i, obj.Name, obj.A, obj.B, obj.getSum()))

if __name__ == '__main__':

    obj1 = CythonObject('obj1', 2, 3)
    obj2 = CythonObject('obj2', 4, 2)

    objs = [obj1, obj2]

    num_rep = 3
    num_pool = 2

    packs = [(obj,obj.pack()) for obj in objs]
    if num_pool==1 or num_rep==1:
        for i in range(num_rep):
            runReplica((i,packs))
    else:
        pool = multiprocessing.Pool(num_pool)
        print ("Running parallelized replicas")
        pool.map(runReplica,[(i,packs) for i in range(num_rep)])
```

Makefile:

```
PYTHON=py -3
PYTHONVERSION=36
PYTHONHOME=C:\Python36
NUMPYINCLUDE=C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include
CYTHON=cython.exe
CC=gcc
RM=rm
RMR= rm -r
MKDIR=mkdir
MKDIRR=mkdir -r
RMDIR=rmdir /s /q
CP=cp
UIC= pyside-uic
RCC= pyside-rcc
DEV=0
DEBUG=0

all:
    make example_pyd

example_pyd:
    $(PYTHON) example_lib_setup.py build_ext --inplace
    -$(RM) example_lib.c

test:
    $(PYTHON) test.py

clean:
ifeq ($(PYTHONVERSION),27)
    $(RM) example_lib.pyd
endif
ifeq ($(PYTHONVERSION),36)
    $(RM) example_lib.cp36-win_amd64.pyd
endif
    -$(RMR) build
```

These was tested on windows 10 platform using Python 3.6.7, cython 0.25.2, Python 2.7.14 and same version of cython (for py2).

In order to compile with python 2 change the related variables values on the Makefile.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi: "TypeError: can't pickle example_lib.CythonObject objects", the thing is, if I pickle the objects outside multiprocessing, no such error occurs.

Comment: I'm getting the same error when using my compiled cython library with multiprocessing on Windows 10. Never had this problem on Python 2.7 on Ubuntu. It would be very good to get a clarification on how to proceed here.

Comment: @phasselmann You should override the objects' '__ getstate __ ' and ' __ setstate __ ' methods. I believe it's a pickling error. That did the trick in my case.

Comment: The function I'm mulprocessing is in Cython, and it is basically a loop that calls a function inside a class... Could you point me to how do I do that overriding? Thanks a lot.

Comment: The problem with this Cython functions is that they use numpy in some parts, so I'm not able to use Cython parallel in this case. The only way would be refurbishing all the procedure...